# Get values and like values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table that contains the following

```
ID     AccountNumber     Name
1      12345             Tony
2      123456            Mike
3      123458            Mike
4      45689             Tom
5      666999            Tim
6      6669997           Lisa
7      44455             Tim
8      78901             Matt
9      789011            Roger
```

What I need to do is show me all records where the Account Number begin with the same value (indeterminate number).  For example.  In this table, I'd want to select and display the following:

```
12345
123456
123458

666999
6669997

78901
789011
```

As you can see, it shows the each row where the AccountNumber matches or has the same beginning number.  I haven't been able to find the proper query and would love any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cases that you mention satisfy that the longer starts with the shorter.  Here is a query that will get the shortest match for each account number:

```
select AccountNumber
from (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by ShortestAN) as numAN
      from (select a.*,
                   (select top 1 a2.AccountNumber
                    from accounts a2
                    where a.AccountNumber like a2.AccountNumber + '%'
                    order by length(a2.AccountNumber) asc
                   ) as ShortestAN
            from accounts a
           ) a
     ) a
where numAN > 1
order by ShortestAN, AccountNumber;
```

The subquery finds the shortest account number that matches.  The rest is just returning the ones where there is more than one match.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a1.ID, a1.AccountNumber, a1.Name, 
a2.ID, a2.AccountNumber, a2.Name
from Accounts a1 
join Accounts a2 on LEN(a1.name) <= LEN(a2.name) and SUBSTRING(a2.name, 1, LEN(a1.name)) = a1.name
where /*are not same rows*/ a1.ID <> a2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Would not an order by work if it were ordering as String?

```
SELECT AccountNumber, Id, Name
FROM Accounts
ORDER BY CAST(AccountNumber AS NVARCHAR(50))
```